# Custom Spinner listener in Android?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

As I am working on getting a custom spinner and displaying the value in toast. The values are setting to the spinner correctly but I am unable to display them in toast. My code is

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity {
ArrayList<String> ast = new ArrayList<String>();
Spinner customspinner;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    customspinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    ast.add("111111");
    ast.add("222222");
    ast.add("333333");
    ast.add("444444");

    MyAdapter adp = new MyAdapter();
    customspinner.setAdapter(adp);
    System.out.println(ast);
    customspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                int position, long val) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //here when spinner was selected I need to save those two custom textviews in two string and need to display them in toast....
            //String getspineer = customspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "spinner  --- " + getspineer , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
    });
}


public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ast.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View v = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customspinner, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        String arlstdate[] = ast.get(position).split("~");
        for (int i = 0; i < arlstdate.length; i++) {
            tv.setText(arlstdate[i]);
            tv1.setText(arlstdate[i]);
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

}

Here what I am looking for is, when I select spinner, I need to save the following two textview values in two string and need to display them in Toast mess seperately.

Can anyone help me with this. After a lot of search I found this code but unable to save to text values in string & display..

Comment: Which two values? It seems you only have 1 string per an adapter item

Comment: here i am setting one array to two textview. I want to display those two textviews when spineer was changed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get exactly what you mean sorry, but as a pointer, the content of the view at that position on the spinner is the same as the string at same position on the ArrayList you used to populate the adapter.

So you can take the value from the ArrayList not from the Spinner View.

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long val) {
        String getspineer = ast.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "spinner  --- " + getspineer , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to display a Toast message:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "put strings here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

To get text from TextView:

```
String text = tv.getText();
```

However, if you only want to display the message in a Toast, you won't need the TextViews and can just use the string array.

Sorry if I didn't understand your question correctly.